# Using unsigned DLLs in project that is signed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a 3rd party DLL that I need to use in my application. My project is signed with an SNK so therefore I cannot use these unsigned DLLs without signing them.

I tried to use ildasm.exe as explained [here](http://buffered.io/posts/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/) but I get error messages when attempting to sign the DLL as the DLL contains unmanaged code. The error message I get is "the resulting PE file is unusable" (the DLL uses P/Invoke calls).

Any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: Software vendors shipping DLLs that don't have a strong name commit a crime.  Especially criminal because it is so easy to do.  You have every right to insist on strong named version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't get a signed version of the third-party assembly and need this to get working, a way out would be to load the dll dynamically at run-time.

Comment: Thanks - this worked :) Ugly but my only option at this point.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest approach is to rebuild the DLL with a key. You haven't told us anything about the 3rd party DLL... if it's a commercial library, I'd expect the company involved to be happy to give you a signed binary. If it's an open source library, you can do that yourself.

If you have no way of getting hold of a "normal" signed binary, perhaps you could give more details about the situation?

Comment: I have asked the company that owns the DLL (it is comercial) to supply me with a signed binary and am awaiting their response. Is there nothing else I can do? What further details would you require in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Vixen: Knowing it's commercial is the detail we were missing. I would be *very* worried if they weren't willing to give you a strongly-named binary - I'd take that as a sign that they're not actually serious about their software.

Comment: Can you use `al.exe` for this purpose?

Comment: @CJ7: I don't know - I thought al was for native code, but I could be very wrong. I haven't used it for ages.

Comment: "that it's commercial" is irrelevant. The question is "can I do it" and the answer is basically "no". Strong signing is the herpes of reusable libraries.